# Add upper right corner "close button" icon to the JQuery lightbox?

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

While searching for a lightbox plugin via Google surfing.  There I end up with the one at http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/lightbox-jquery-css/ and the source code is available there.

The script is short, simple and customizable.  Then I noticed it doesn't have a close button icon.  The guy on the webpage said "you could easily add a “close” button to your lightbox by connecting it to the closeLightbox();" but I don't see an example nor do I know how exactly to accomplish that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added to the original code the close button and some styling for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/FMnn6/

```
var close = $('<a href="#" class="x">x</a>');
close
    .appendTo('#lightbox')
    .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        closeLightbox();
    });
```

Comment: Not bad.  I don't know a whole lot about JQuery but I'm learning.  That will do.